# Is the Euler characteristc defined wrong? If not, why not?

Tags: definition, surfaces, polyhedra

Ever since learning that $$\chi(S_0\# S_1) = \chi(S_0)+\chi(S_1)-2$$

(where $\chi$ denote the [Euler characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic)), I've wondered whether $\chi$ isn't "defined wrong." If we let $\chi' = 2-\chi,$ then we get a genuine "homomorphism":

$$\chi'(S_0\# S_1) = \chi'(S_0)+\chi'(S_1)$$

So it is natural to ask whether or not $$\chi' = 2-V+E-F$$ is the "correct" Euler characterstic.

Obviously, smart people have thought about this before. What is the verdict? Is $\chi'$ more fundamental than $\chi$, and if not, why not?

---

*Discussion.* I think its curious that $\chi' = 1-V+E-F+1$. If we can interpret that two hanging $1$'s, that would motivate $\chi'$ on geometric grounds.

Comment: The $-2$ comes from $\#$ (connect sum) being the wrong operation. If you consider $\sqcup$ (disjoint union), which is a more natural choice anyway from the point of view of category theory, then you do in fact have
$$\chi(M\sqcup N)=\chi(M)+\chi(N)$$

Comment: It is «only more natural» if you are doing something for which it is more natural... The «point of view of category theory» does not exist: you could well be working in the category of connected manifolds!

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me that connect sum is actually the coproduct in the category of connected manifolds (I have trouble visualizing the inclusion maps). Is the connect sum meaningful categorically in any way?

Comment: That something is not the coproduct is not exactly grounds for dismissal! For example, the connected sum is the operation that you need in order to construct Milnor's group of smooth structures on spheres. That it is not the coproduct did not stop him :-)

Comment: His theorem stating that $3$-manifolds are uniquely the conncted sum of prime ones shows that he thought well of connected sums, too, I guess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The usual Euler characteristic is absolutely the correct choice, at least for closed manifolds. There are lots of reasons to believe this:

1. $\chi(X \sqcup Y) = \chi(X) + \chi(Y)$, where $\sqcup$ is the disjoint union. (This is the coproduct in the category of, say, topological spaces.) Under some conditions we even have the "inclusion-exclusion" formula $\chi(X \cup Y) = \chi(X) + \chi(Y) - \chi(X \cap Y)$.
2. $\chi(X \times Y) = \chi(X) \chi(Y)$. So we even get a "ring homomorphism."
3. If $X \to Y$ is an $n$-fold covering map, then $\chi(X) = n \chi(Y)$.
4. For closed surfaces, $\chi(X)$ naturally appears in the [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem). This is part of a major division in the theory of surfaces between the surfaces that admit Riemannian metrics of constant negative curvature, constant zero curvature, and constant positive curvature, which by the Gauss-Bonnet theorem corresponds to having negative Euler characteristic, zero Euler characteristic, and positive Euler characteristic. See also the [uniformization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem). In higher dimensions we have the [Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem).
5. $\chi(X)$ also naturally appears in the [Poincaré–Hopf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem), which among other things singles out closed smooth manifolds of Euler characteristic $0$ among all closed smooth manifolds: these are precisely the ones which admit nonvanishing vector fields.
6. A slight generalization of the Euler characteristic, the *Lefschetz trace* $L(f)$ of an endomorphism $f : X \to X$, naturally appears in the [Lefschetz fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem). The Euler characteristic turns out to be the Lefschetz trace $L(\text{id}_X)$ of the identity. Compare to the statement that the dimension of a vector space is the trace of its identity; there is a way to formalize the sense in which the Euler characteristic of a closed manifold is its "homotopy dimension" or "homotopy cardinality." See also [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/euler-characteristic-as-homotopy-cardinality/), although I think I stated something incorrect in the introduction.

The connected sum is a less natural operation to consider than you might believe. Most importantly, you need to choose where to cut little holes out of your manifolds (and the choice matters e.g. if your manifolds are not connected). It should be thought of not as an operation on manifolds but as an operation on manifolds after you've chosen little holes to cut out of them, where it just becomes composition (gluing) of [cobordisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism). And it's this extra cutting step that alters the behavior of the Euler characteristic from the homomorphism property you might expect: with suitable hypotheses, cutting a hole out of a surface decreases its Euler characteristic by $1$.

For closed  connected surfaces, the alternative number you define is the first Betti number $b_1 = \dim H_1(X, \mathbb{Q})$ of the surface. Its relevance to taking connected sums is that

$$H_1(X \# Y, \mathbb{Q}) \cong H_1(X, \mathbb{Q}) \oplus H_1(X, \mathbb{Q})$$

but don't read too much into this: the analogous statements for $H_0$ and $H_2$ are both false.

Comment: For noncompact manifolds there is a choice which is arguably better in a few senses called the compactly supported Euler characteristic; it isn't homotopy invariant, but it satisfies a stronger version of inclusion-exclusion than the ordinary Euler characteristic. But it agrees with the Euler characteristic on closed manifolds.

Answer (score 1):

If you did that, you'd just move the $2$ to other places. For example, you'd have state the Poincaré-Hopf theorem as follows:

**Theorem.** If $S$ is a surface and $\chi'(S)\neq2$, then there is no nonzero tangent vector field to $S$.

Comment: OTOH in many contexts it is the reduced Euler characteristic which is the correct choice.